# ValueSerializer, SerializationException and DLT, how to make it works for serialization?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm exploring Spring Boot with Kafka, and I'm facing a problem with DLT and its serializer.

In my DLT, I want all messages that caused a SerializationException, and all (valid) messages that caused technical or functionnal exception. My message is a XML message, that I can deserialize easily in a deserializer and an object generated by JAXB.

The problem is the value serializer :

- If I send stupid message (not a XML, but a random string...) that causes SerializationException, I need ByteArraySerializer. (`record.value()` is `Byte[]`)
- If I have a technical or functionnal exception, I need a MyObjectSerializer... (`record.value()` is `MyObject`)

How to handle that problem ?
(Using spring-kafka 2.5.5 right now, with kafka-client 2.5.1)

The best thing I managed to make it works with both is a Object Serializer, but I loose the string format of MyObject...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`, use one of these constructors...

```java
/**
 * Create an instance with the provided templates and a default destination resolving
 * function that returns a TopicPartition based on the original topic (appended with
 * ".DLT") from the failed record, and the same partition as the failed record.
 * Therefore the dead-letter topic must have at least as many partitions as the
 * original topic. The templates map keys are classes and the value the corresponding
 * template to use for objects (producer record values) of that type. A
 * {@link java.util.LinkedHashMap} is recommended when there is more than one
 * template, to ensure the map is traversed in order. To send records with a null
 * value, add a template with the {@link Void} class as a key; otherwise the first
 * template from the map values iterator will be used.
 * @param templates the {@link KafkaOperations}s to use for publishing.
 */
public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(Map<Class<?>, KafkaOperations<? extends Object, ? extends Object>> templates) {



/**
 * Create an instance with the provided templates and destination resolving function,
 * that receives the failed consumer record and the exception and returns a
 * {@link TopicPartition}. If the partition in the {@link TopicPartition} is less than
 * 0, no partition is set when publishing to the topic. The templates map keys are
 * classes and the value the corresponding template to use for objects (producer
 * record values) of that type. A {@link java.util.LinkedHashMap} is recommended when
 * there is more than one template, to ensure the map is traversed in order. To send
 * records with a null value, add a template with the {@link Void} class as a key;
 * otherwise the first template from the map values iterator will be used.
 * @param templates the {@link KafkaOperations}s to use for publishing.
 * @param destinationResolver the resolving function.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(Map<Class<?>, KafkaOperations<? extends Object, ? extends Object>> templates,
        BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, TopicPartition> destinationResolver) {
```

They take a `Map` of `KafkaOperations` keyed by the value type.

You can either create two producer factories, or just override the serializer using this constructor...

```java
/**
 * Create an instance using the supplied producer factory and properties, with
 * autoFlush false. If the configOverrides is not null or empty, a new
 * {@link DefaultKafkaProducerFactory} will be created with merged producer properties
 * with the overrides being applied after the supplied factory's properties.
 * @param producerFactory the producer factory.
 * @param configOverrides producer configuration properties to override.
 * @since 2.5
 */
public KafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory, @Nullable Map<String, Object> configOverrides) {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters

Comment: Seems nice. I check that :) Thank you.

Comment: Another quesiton linked to this topic. 

Is that possible to wrap object in error in another object ? 
Like a MyObject object in error, and I want to wrap it into a object ErrorObject to send at the DLQ.

Comment: It's best to ask a new question so others can find it (and the answer). You can subclass the DLPR and override the `createProducerRecord` method. `Subclasses can override this method to customize the producer record to send to the DLQ. The default implementation simply copies the key and value from the consumer record and adds the headers.`